# How to read the video frame and frame time file simultaneously using vlcj

Tags: java, video, vlc, libvlc, vlcj

I am working on VLCJ. I want to play a video where every frame's duration time is recorded in an independent file. So I plan to modify the input module of VLCJ in order to read the video content file and frame time file at the same time. Finally, the result should be VLCJ playing the video frame by frame and frame time file decides how long a video frame is playing.

To implement this, anybody knows which modules of VLCJ source code should be modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not even sure you can do this with libvlc - do you mean the amount of time the frame should display for on the screen or actually does? If you mean *should*, then you should just be able to calculate this from the frame rate.

If you mean does then you might want to look at an API such as [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/) which works with each frame directly.